# What syntax does a scaleXY animation in React Native require?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Using React Native's [experimental animation library](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Animation/AnimationExperimental.js), what `toValue` is required to animate the scaling of an element to `0`?

This does nothing:

```
Animation.startAnimation({
  node: button,
  duration: 500,
  easing: 'easeInQuad',
  property: 'scaleXY',
  toValue: [0,0]
});
```

A `toValue` of `{x:0,y:0}` also fails. Providing a `fromValue` does nothing.

A `toValue` of `0` gives the error `JSON value '0' of type 'NSNumber' cannot be converted to CGPoint`.

Animation is working for other properties, e.g. `position`, but not with `scaleXY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scaleXY` is a point, so it should be:

```
toValue: { x: value, y: value}
```

See [this usage from one of the React Native components](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1d1386e7355fcd269aefea415e3a174b529917da/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableBounce.js#L90).

However, AnimationExperimental is deprecated. See the documentation for other options:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#content